# Ошибки при записи файла

Tags: android

Когда методы записи и чтения из файла были в главном Activity - все работало. Создал отдельный класс для I/O, вызываю методы через его экземпляр. Постоянно то NullPointerException, то FileNotFound.
Вот код и ошибка:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("tasksLogs",MODE_PRIVATE)));
//Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileOutputStream android.content.Context.openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

А если изменить код вот так, то выдает FileNotFound на второй строчке с FileOutputStream.

```
    File file = new File("tasksLogs");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(outputStream);
```

Класс IOclass целиком (поправил, убрал наследование):

```
package com.example.jur.list;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class IOclass {

    void writeFile(String s) {
        try {
            //BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("tasksLogs",MODE_PRIVATE)));
            File file = new File("tasksLogs.bin");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(outputStream);

            bw.write(s);
            bw.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void loadFileIn(HashMap<String,String> map) {
        try {
            //BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("tasksLogs", MODE_PRIVATE)));
            File file = new File("tasksLogs.bin");
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStream);

            String str = "";
            Object[] x;
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                x = str.split(" ");
                map.put(x[0].toString(),x[1].toString());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке не инициализирован контекст.

Comment: У файла не надо разве расширение указывать? И покажите целиком класс для I/O

Comment: В главном не указывал, работало. Выложил код. Если ошибка в отсутствии setContentView(R.layout.ioclass); - то это же не активность.

Comment: вы понимаете, какое количество не нужного кода вы добавляете в ваш класс наследуясь от активити, если используете ее не по назначению?

Comment: @keltkelt если это не активность, то зачем наследуете от активности? И экземпляр класса, наверное, создаете через new, а это активити

Comment: @pavlofff без нее строка "openFileOutput" подсвечивалась красным, попробовал довериться среде.  А как иначе сделать? Если сделать метод статическим - то Запись/Чтение ругаются, что не статические.

Comment: @Likhanov да, через new. Я и сам пока new, вот такие глупости делаю...

Comment: Убрал наследование, всеравно FileNotFound на строчке  FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);  Расширение тоже добавил. Обновил код класса в вопросе.

Comment: Нашел вот что! Может быть в этом проблема. https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/38101/ Да, у меня как раз эти методы не работают без наследования... А без них видимо не записать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что метод `openFileOutput()` это метод класса `Context`.

Создавая активити через `new`, вы не создаёте системный контроллер, наследующий контекст, а просто экземпляр класса (а с системными компонентами так нельзя, если вы хотите иметь их функциональность), поэтому получаете ошибку отсутствия контекста.

Решение вашей проблемы. Создать обычный класс, через его конструктор передавать контекст из реальной активити, из этого контекста вызывать ваш метод:

```
public class IOclass{
     Context context;
     public IOclass (Context context){
         this.context = context;
     }
        void someMetod(){
            ..  context.openFileOutput()..
        }
}
```

Comment: Премного благодарен!

Comment: В активити делаю так.  IOclass io = new IOclass(this); Верно? Это можно использовать в любой активити? Пока почему-то не пишется, но ошибки исчезли. Буду копать дальше.

Comment: да, все верно, да в любой активити. еще вместо this можно использовать `getContext()`, фактически это одно и тоже